# Extracting Text with VBA Excel and Tesseract

Tags: excel, vba, tesseract

I've been trying to use the code below to extract text from a png image, but without success. It doesn't generate an error, but it doesn't generate anything. I have the 64-bit Wind and I've tried with the 32-bit and 64-bit tesseract and the result is the same, that is, it doesn't generate any output... I got this example from the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VP54f0xV-E

```
Sub Image_into_Excelby_Ajit_Yadav()
  
  Dim myshell As Shell32.Shell, ReadCommand, CaptchaCode, i
  Set myshell = New Shell32.Shell

  For i = 1 To 5 ' Change it
      ReadCommand = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe " & "'C:\Temp\Sem.png'" & " " & "'C:\Temp\Sem'" & " ' -l eng'"
      myshell.ShellExecute "powershell", vArgs:=ReadCommand, vShow:=0
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
      
      Open "C:\Temp\Sem.txt" For Input As #1
      Line Input #1, CaptchaCode
      Close #1
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
      MyCaptchaCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CaptchaCode, Chr(10), "")
      Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(MyCaptchaCode))
      Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "Sr. " & i
   Next i
End Sub
```

To create the image, I took a print screen and saved it in paint

[image]

Test being done on a 64-bit win 10 and with the environment variable properly configured and the reference of the dll Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation

Comment: Have you tried running the command directly in PowerShell instead of running via VBA? This way you'll see the error message if there is one directly in the console.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` ignores all run-time errors.

Comment: It is giving me error: 62 - Input past end of file in row: Line Input #1, CaptchaCode

Comment: I tried to run the instruction tesseract.exe "C:\Temp\Sem.png" "C:\Temp\Sem" -l eng in powershell, but it tells me that it is not a cmdlet command

Comment: My environment variable looks like this: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\

Comment: Which environment variable? `Path`? At the user or system level? Also, did you make sure that `tesseract.exe` is located in that exact folder (no typos)?

Comment: As I have installed 32bit tesseract so it is in my Prorgam Files (x86) folder. In the environment variables it is in the system part like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR... That is, at the system level

Comment: So, seems like you need to change the value in your `Path` variable to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR" instead of "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\" to make it work in Powershell. Also note that you can always specify the full path of the exe to make sure Powershell can find it.

Comment: @DecimalTurn: 
I already did that, but the error persists

Comment: Does anyone have an example that is working and can post here, please

Comment: @GutembergSilveiraAlvesGTTJ I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254911/extracting-text-with-vba-excel-and-tesseract) for further discussions.

Comment: This question was solved like this with the help of colleague DecimalTurn:

where it reads

ReadCommand = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe " & "'C:\Temp\Sem.png'" & " " & "'C:\Temp\Sem'" & " ' -l eng'"

It looked like this:

ReadCommand = "& 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' " & "'C:\temp\Sem.png'" & " " & "'C:\temp\Sem'" & " - l by"

This test was performed on 64-bit tesseract on a 64-bit win 10 and the environment variable looked like this at user level: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the full path name of the exe file, you'll need to use single or double quotes around the path of your exe precedeed with a `&` (which is the call operator). This is needed because you have spaces in the file path and the way PowerShell deals with spaces.

```
ReadCommand = "& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' " & "'C:\Temp\Sem.png'" & " " & "'C:\Temp\Sem'" & " ' -l eng'"
```

Regarding the use of the `Path` environment variable to use the command without the full path, you'll have to restart Excel for it to take effect (based on the tests I've done).

As discussed in the comment, you'd also be better off trying the command directly in the PowerShell terminal to make sure that it works properly before trying to implement it in VBA.

The PowerShell command:

```
tesseract.exe 'C:\Temp\Sem.png' 'C:\Temp\Sem' -l eng
```

Note that in the a PowerShell command executed in the console directly, you don't have to surround the last argument `-l eng` with single quotes, otherwise you'll get an error.